# In java, how to create HttpsURLConnection or HttpURLConnection based on the url?

Tags: java, urlconnection

I'm working on a project where I'm creating a class to run http client requests (my class acts as a client).  It takes in a url and a request method (GET, POST, PUT, etc) and I want to be able to parse the URL and open a HttpsURLConnection or HttpURLConnection based on whether it is https or http (assume the given urls will always be correct).

If I do the following:

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
```

Then that will automatically create a URLConnection that can accept both http and https, but if I do this then I can't find any way to set a request method (GET, POST, etc), since only the HttpsURLConnection or HttpURLConnection classes have the setRequestMethod method.

If I do something like the following:

```
if(is_https)
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
else
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Then the connections are created, but I can't access them outside of the if blocks.

Is it possible to do this, or should I just give up and use the apache httpclient classes?

Comment: Just define *conn* before the *if* statement. You need to read up on variable scope.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[HttpsURLConnection](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) extends [HttpUrlConnection](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), so you do not need the HttpsUrlConnection, you can just do

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Comment: Problems exude with this in an age when HTTPS is becoming more and more required.

Comment: Yes, this is taking advantage of Java polymorphism. JVM will call method from appropriate class when using such conn. So type checking like if(is_https) doesn't make sense in this case. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Answer (score 22):

since `HttpsURLConnection extends HttpURLConnection` you can declare `conn` as `HttpsURLConnection`. In this way you can access the common interface (`setRequestMethod()`).

In order to access the extension methods (like `getCipherSuite()`, defined only in the child class `HttpsURLConnection`) you must use a cast after an **instanceof**:

```
if (conn instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
    HttpsURLConnection secured = (HttpsURLConnection) conn;
    String cipher = secured.getCipherSuite();
}
```