# HttpUrlConnection to HttpsUrlConnection, can i just add the 's'?

Tags: java, android, httprequest, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection

I have developed an android application that is successfully sending data from my mobile application to my `REST service` and then to a database using `httpurlconnection`. However, I have been asked that I use `httpsurlconnection` as the REST service will be hosted in a secure location.

My requests include the `url` then opening a connection object. I have authorization headers and then I send through the data as a `JSON object`.

Can I simply add the 's' to the `httpurlconnection` or what other aspects do I need to think about?

Would appreciate the help, Thanks!

Comment: `HttpUrlConnection` could handle both, http and https connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In java, how to create HttpsURLConnection or HttpURLConnection based on the url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945003/in-java-how-to-create-httpsurlconnection-or-httpurlconnection-based-on-the-url)

Comment: @AnggrayudiH It's rather the other way round, since ``HttpsUrlConnection`` extends ``HttpUrlConnection``.

Comment: @Matt does this explain the error I am getting under the post below? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Android documentation:

> Calling openConnection() on a URL with the "https" scheme will return an HttpsURLConnection

So yes, you can simply cast your returned connection to `HttpsURLConnection` when calling `openConnection()`. In most cases there's nothing else you need to do; the SSL certificate, handshakes, and everything else related to the HTTPS protocol is handled by the system.

Comment: great! I seen that on the documentation but I thought I might need to overwrite the SSL socket layer and other things.. thanks!

Comment: actually received this error :                 V/ErrorAPP: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.

Comment: HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) object.openConnection(); ... this is how I have set up my object.. any ideas?